# Python - formatting ticks on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, axis-labels, economics

I'm working with some code that plots 3 different time series in one graph with subplots, where the time axis displays every 12th time series using the following code

```
df_sub = df[['EPU', 'VIX_beg_month','BAA_bonds_minus_1yr']]
variables = list((df_sub.columns.values))
time = df['Date']
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, dpi=120, figsize=(10,6))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    data = df_sub[df_sub.columns[i]]
    ax.plot(time, data, color='red', linewidth=1)
    # Decorations
    ax.set_title(df_sub.columns[i])    
    ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::18])
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    ax.spines["top"].set_alpha(0)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=6)

plt.tight_layout();
```

This seems to work just fine.  See the attached screenshot.
[image]
Later in my code, I am running impulse response functions and plotting those with almost identical code, and am having issues with it plotting the time axis correctly.

This is the code for those plots.

```
T = 36
time3 = np.linspace(0,T,T+1)

#Plot Impulse Response Functions
zeros = np.zeros(T+1)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, dpi=120, figsize=(10,6))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    #plot the IRFs
    data = IRF_data_EPU[i]
    ax.plot(time3, data, color='blue', linewidth=1)
    #plot the IRF standard error bands
    lower = IRF_lower_EPU[i]
    upper = IRF_upper_EPU[i]
    ax.plot(lower, '--', color='black', linewidth=1)
    ax.plot(upper, '--', color='black', linewidth=1)
    #include a line for the x axis at zero
    ax.plot(zeros, color='black',linewidth=1)
    # Decorations
    ax.set_title(df_sub.columns[i])
    ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::3])
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    ax.spines["top"].set_alpha(0)
    ax.tick_params(labelsize=6)

plt.tight_layout();
```

However, running this code creates issues with the x-axis.  Instead of displaying every third value from 0 to 36, the x axis is plotting values from -5 to 40 and then using seemingly random values for the ticks.

This is the graph before adding the code for the ticks on the x-axis
[image]

And this is the graph with the ticks set.  The only part of the code that was changed was adding the line for ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::3])
[image]

I've tried to comment out plotting anything other than the impulse responses, but that doesn't fix it, so something is wrong with plotting the data against the time sequence.

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: I've added images of the graphs from the code output.  Hope this helps!